# error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'Base*' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, классы, указатели

В цикле вводятся значения типа float либо знак действия между числами и после этого они должны либо складываться, либо вычитаться. Попробовал сначала сделать только сложение но не могу разобраться почему не работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Base{
private:

public:
    virtual void getdata(){}

    virtual void display(){}

    friend Base operator+(Base &base){
        return base;
    }

};

class Float : public Base{
public:
    float n;

    void getdata(){
        cin >> n;
    }

    void display(){
        cout << n;
    }

    friend Float operator+(float k, Float &f) {
        f.n += k;
        return f;
    }
};

class Char : public Base{
public:
    char ch;

    void getdata(){
        cin >> ch;
    }

    void display(){
        cout << ch;
    }

    friend Char operator+(char k, Char &aChar) {
        aChar.ch += k;
        return aChar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b[100];

    int i = 0;
    for (char choice = 'y'; choice == 'y'; cin >> choice){
        i++;
        if (i % 2 != 0){
            cout << "Enter float number: ";
            b[i] = new Float;
            b[i]->getdata();
        }else{
            cout << "Enter action: ";
            b[i] = new Char;
            b[i]->getdata();
        }
        cout << "Continue? (y/n): ";
    }

    float sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        sum = sum + b[i];
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Проблема в последних строчках, сложение никак не хочет работать, скорее всего где то накосячил с friend

```
float sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        sum += b[j];
        cout << &b[j] << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в сложении

```
sum = sum + b[i];
```

Но что вы складываете? Переменную типа `float`

```
float sum = 0;
```

с *указателем*. Ведь переменная `b` объявлена как

```
Base *b[100];
```

т.е. массив из 100 указателей на `Base`. Такая арифметика — сложение числа с плавающей точкой и указателя — в С++ не предусмотрена...

Если считать, что у вас строчка

```
sum += b[j];
```

(у вас один раз так, другой — иначе), то ничего не меняется. Нет для обычного `float` такого оператора.